# Symfony sfGuardPlugin: disable default routes

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, sfguard

I'm using the sfGuardPlugin in symfony 1.4 and I'm wondering how to get rid of its "default" routes. I mean by that the "guard/users", "guard/permissions" and "guard/groups" routes.

Indeed I have designed my own backend without admin generator, and I've recreated these three pages with customs urls. So how can I disable the access to the default sfGuard pages ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To desactivate these 3 modules : you just have to remove the sfGuardGroup, sfGuardUser, sfGuardPermission from the settings.yml for backend application.

```
all:
  .settings:
    enabled_modules: [default, sfGuardAuth, sfGuardGroup, sfGuardUser, sfGuardPermission]
```

In order to keep only the authentification module

```
all:
  .settings:
    enabled_modules: [default, sfGuardAuth]
```

However I have no idea what default is.

Comment: the default module is the original Symfony one. For instance the default 404 error page is there, as well as the brown "symfony project created" welcome page. It is somewhere within the lib/vendor/symfony dir

Answer (score 2):

app.yml:

```
all:
  sf_guard_plugin:
    routes_register: false
```

as stated in the [documentation](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfGuardPlugin).

Comment: Thanks Maerlyn for your answer, I tried that but even after having clear the cache I can access the `backend_dev.php/guard/users` URL (and the others too). Any idea ?

Comment: Yes, delete the default `/:module/:action` route from your routing.yml file.

Comment: I already did :( The only routes available in my rooting.yml (for the tests) are sf_guard_signin, sf_guard_signout and sf_guard_password (as stated in the doc). On the other hand the `backend_dev.php/sfGuardUsers` is disable.

Answer (score 2):

You should update the file

/config/sfDoctrineGuardPluginConfiguration.class.php

to the lasted version.

Before the lasted update, despite the documentation, the routes did get registed anyway.

It seems you are using the previous version of this file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually it was up to date but you pointed me to the right direction. See Mikolaj's answer.

Comment: Just had this issue. [See here](http://trac.symfony-project.org/ticket/8573) for more information

Answer (score 1):

If you (i) still want to use the modules provided by the plugin, (ii) using your own routes, (iii) preventing people from using the default sfGuard routes and (iv) still have the default /:module/:action route (which is rather useful), you can override the sfGuardRouting class, which is here

> plugins/sfGuardPlugin/lib/routing/sfGuardRouting.class.php

You can simply copy this file to your

> lib/

directory and then play with the methods. For instance I just commented all the code of all methods of the class (since I made my own routes in my apps/myApp/config/routing.yml file) for the modules of the sfGuardPlugin), like this

```
class sfGuardRouting
{
  static public function listenToRoutingLoadConfigurationEvent(sfEvent $event)
  {
   //    $r = $event->getSubject();
   // preprend our routes
   //    $r->prependRoute('sf_guard_signin', new sfRoute('/guard/login', array('module' => 'sfGuardAuth', 'action' => 'signin'))); 
   //    $r->prependRoute('sf_guard_signout', new sfRoute('/guard/logout', array('module' => 'sfGuardAuth', 'action' => 'signout'))); 
  }
}
```